# How to validate physical address with time zone

Tags: java, android, validation, timezone

I am implementing an Android application in Java and I wanted to be able to validate the user's physical address information with the user's time zone. For example, the user can input Japan Standard Time, but the address could be in USA, which is obviously wrong. How would I validate this? I am using TimeZonePicker from AOSP to get the time zone details.

I know I could check the country of the time zone and the country listed by the user in the physical address, but some countries have multiple time zones so this wouldn't work in every case. It would probably be best I think to use city, state, and country since states like Tennessee have multiple time zones in the state.

Comment: For the countries that have multiple time zones , I think you should check the State too

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani Yes, I agree. city, state, and country.

Comment: Yes , So what is the issue ?

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani Checking if a String city and state belong to a certain time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Query the Google Time Zone API to return the state and timezone of the location provided.

If you are not using any of the location providing sensors, you can reverse geolocate the address to latitude and longitude coordinates.

Once you have the coordinates, query Google TimeZone API

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=API_KEY

You will get obtain response with time zone name and timezone id:

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0.0,
   "rawOffset" : -28800.0,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}
```

Validation logic after this point is up to you.